# Lombok annotation handler class lombok.javac.handlers.HandleData failed

Tags: java, inheritance, lombok

I am trying to use lombok it in a project where I have a abstract base model class and other classes are deriving from it. However I am getting error while compiling. Code looks like this:

BaseEntity.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Data
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date modifiedOn;
    private Status status;
}
```

User.java

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    public static enum UserType {
        GUEST, NORMAL, SELLER, ADMIN, SUPER_ADMIN
    }

    public static enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE, NOT_SPECIFIED
    }

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    private String password;
    private long phoneNumber;
    private Gender gender;
    private UserType userType;
    private Address address;
}
```

While compiling i am getting error

```
[ERROR] Lombok annotation handler class lombok.javac.handlers.HandleData failed on D:\BolBuddy\bolbuddy\api\bolbuddy\src\main\java\in\bolbuddy\model\User.java: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.<init>(ILcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol$TypeSymbol;)V

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.<init>(ILcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol$TypeSymbol;)V
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleSetter$JCNoType.<init>(HandleSetter.java:167)
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleSetter.createSetter(HandleSetter.java:154)
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleSetter.createSetterForField(HandleSetter.java:127)
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleSetter.generateSetterForField(HandleSetter.java:89)
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleData.handle(HandleData.java:111)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary$AnnotationHandlerContainer.handle(HandlerLibrary.java:74)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.handleAnnotation(HandlerLibrary.java:168)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTransformer$AnnotationVisitor.visitAnnotationOnType(JavacTransformer.java:71)
    at lombok.javac.JavacNode.traverse(JavacNode.java:103)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.traverseChildren(JavacAST.java:117)
    at lombok.javac.JavacNode.traverse(JavacNode.java:66)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.traverseChildren(JavacAST.java:117)
    at lombok.javac.JavacNode.traverse(JavacNode.java:61)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.traverse(JavacAST.java:112)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTransformer.transform(JavacTransformer.java:52)
    at lombok.javac.apt.Processor.process(Processor.java:105)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

UPDATE:
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>in.bolbuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>bolbuddy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bolbuddy</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>projectlombok.org</id>
            <url>http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use an old version of Java. Which JDK do you have?

Comment: Java 8 Update 60
And lombok version 0.9.2

Comment: Please post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @chrylis Added pom.xml

Comment: Why are you using Lombok 0.9.2 instead of 1.16.6?

Comment: Thanks! Changing dependency to version 1.16.6 resolved issue.

Comment: I've found that this problem can also be caused if you have a variable with the name val

Answer (score 15):

in your `pom.xml` file, replace

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>RELEASE</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It worked for me. I was facing similar problem while trying to `mvn clean install`.